# MySQL join returns null

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join on authors_2's `authorID` column and author_note's `aaID` column:

Table authors_2:

```
 id   |   name   |   aaID   |   authorID

 1    |   jimmy   |  11129  |   1734
 2    |   mike    |  15813  |   2469
 3    |   jane    |  10849  |   9853
```

Table author_note:

```
 id   |   note   |   aaID   

 1    |   note1   |  1734   
 2    |   note2   |  2469   
 3    |   note3   |  9853
```

I've tried `select * from A left join author_note on author_note.aaID = authors_2.authorID;` but everything that comes back from table B is null. What's the proper way to do this join?

Comment: Where is author_note ? Didn't you call that table A ?  Is table A actually author_note and table B actually authors_2 ?

Comment: It's a poor design to have `aaID` mean two different things in different tables.  The column in table B sholud be called `authorID`.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1):

Your table names don't match.  If those are the real names of tables A and B, then please use those in your example.  This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.aaID = A.authorID;
```

Comment: Whoops, edited accordingly, not actually using A and B for table names. That's what I tried and it is bringing back all nulls for author_note table.

Comment: All nulls for what fields?  Perhaps you should show us your exact results.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for that join is indeed.

```
SELECT * FROM authors_2 LEFT JOIN author_note ON authors_2.authorID = author_note.aaID
```

Is the example providing real snippet of data? Are you sure that the aaID on the authors_2 table does not correlate with the author_note aaID?

As mentioned by [@Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) it is poor practice to use different named columns when referencing keys from other tables. It makes it hard to know you are referencing the proper fields.

The proper join would be this

```
SELECT * FROM authors_2 LEFT JOIN author_note ON authors_2.aaID = author_note.aaID
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like there's a mistake in your join condition. You mentioned that you want to join on authors_2's authorID column and author_note's aaID column. However, in your SQL query, you are trying to join on author_note.aaID = authors_2.authorID. It should be the other way around. Try the this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM authors_2
LEFT JOIN author_note ON authors_2.authorID = author_note.aaID;
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between those two join conditions.  The `=` operator is commutative.

Comment: Oh srry I don't know MySQL too much

Comment: You probably shouldn't be answering questions outside of your expertise unless you are absolutely sure.  Answers like this collect downvotes, which affects your reputation score.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).